How does harmonic progression work in modes which aren't Ionian and Aeolian?
I have seen some similar questions to this but nothing that quite cuts close enough.
In major and minor, it is widely considered that harmonic progression works as follows (broadly speaking- don't flag me up on this as I know they are not 'rules'):
Chord I- can go anywhere
II- moves to V (sometimes IV)
III- moves to VI
IV- moves to I or II (sometimes VI)
V- moves to VI, VII OR I
VI- Moves to IV or II
VII- moves to I, VI or V
This is basically the same for both major and minor- with a few exceptions.
However, down to the way 'tendency tones' work, to me it seems that we cannot say that this will work for the rest of the modes. For instance, will chord VI in Dorian want to move to chord II in Dorian? Using the above framework, chord VI in Dorian (chord VII in major) will want to move to chord VII in Dorian, chord V in Dorian and IV in Dorian, but not chord II.
So, is it simply the case that chords have the same gravitational pull to each other regardless of tonal centre, and we just translate the same chordal relationships from the perspective of a different mode (as done here in Dorian, in this case); or does the new tonal centre actually effect where these tendency tones want to go?

See also How are chord progressions built in a modal context vs traditional major/minor context?; Modal Chord Progressions; How are chord progressions built in a modal context vs traditional major/minor context?; and others.

"we cannot say that this will work for the rest of the modes": this is why major and minor tonality evolved from the Dorian, Phrygian, Lydian, and Mixolydian modes, the only four that theorists recognized initially.  The Aeolian and Ionian modes were invented later to describe actual practice, which consisted of altering the original four modes because of tendency tones.  Modern modal compositions, on the other hand, seek to break away from common-practice tonality, so they don't necessarily follow similar functional patterns.  Which iteration of modality are you interested in?

Which iteration of modality are you interested in?  If you're asking for example about classical music of the late 19th and early 20th centuries, the answer will be far different from that for Renaissance music or rock music of the 60s and 70s.  Depending on which kind of modal music you're asking about, the supposed duplicate questions may be helpful or they may be irrelevant.

Note: there are some assumptions here that feel pretty basic but are not universal: That there "are chords," and that they "go to other chords." There are many modal musics that don't include these assumptions, including western music history before Baroque.

@AndyBonner while theorists of the time hadn't perhaps articulated it in the same terms, chords and harmonic progressions were certainly a prominent aspect of Renaissance music.  The idea that nobody thought of chords until figured bass was invented (or whenever) is highly improbable.  It seems rather more likely that chordal thinking was the critical factor that allowed the invention of figured bass.  There must have been an awareness of chordal harmony by the 16th century; it's difficult to imagine that even the generation before Josquin didn't have some awareness of chords as such.
